# What is the best way to measure performance time of android app?

Tags: android, query-performance

I tested two ways of query processing time.
The first one is currentTimeMillis().
The second one is startMethodTracingSampling.
I got different result times of using two of them.
I wanna know which is the best way to measure.
Thanks to you.
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The "best" way is to use the tools provided by Google called the Performance Profiler Tools. They are built into android studio and let you profile your app performance and show other interesting information without you having to add any code.

See https://developer.android.com/studio/profile/index.html